# Run process via BAT file as super user

Tags: windows, security, batch-file

My Scenario looks like:
There is a Appache Tomcat 8 Server where a Schedular-application runs on. Via a browser i can start tasks there and configure the parameters for these tasks. 
The tasks itself containing jobs which are like a single command line execution with needed parameters. Therefore i usually call bat files in there.

The problem in a special case the job-process need to have administrator rights.
I know how to use runas and i know how to run processes as administrator. But i dont know how to automate the authentication via a bat.

What could be a way to do this?

p.s.: all articles i found need at least one click to go ahead with authentication however thats not possible in the given scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me. I just create link to the batch file by doing these i can set the default run as administrator. In addition to lower the uac of level in windows the execution works with no interupts.